# When I try to upload my Voip app on play store it gives error

Tags: android

I am facing problem to roll-out app on play store.
When I try to save changes then it gives error that "Your changes could not be saved. Please try again". 
In this app, I used "android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" permission for outgoing call handling.
And moreover I fill up declaration permissions form for SMS and CALL_Log permission which I have not used in latest attached build but still it does not allowed to save my changes.

Please help me to resolved this issue.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am trying to push app change that has SMS permissions removed, but I still receive same error for a week now!